# Is this testing positive semi-definiteness of the matrix or of its conjugate?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, self-adjoint-operators

This may sound pedantic but maybe it helps me clarify some misunderstanding.
The setup is as follows:
Let $A$ be a complex $n\times n$ matrix which is self-adjoint, i.e. $A^*=A$, wherein $*$ denotes the conjugate of the transpose of $A$.
Now to state that $A$ is in addition positive semi-definite one has to check that
\begin{equation}\label{pos}\langle x, Ax \rangle \geq 0\end{equation} holds.

Now, I read some time series book and in the text the author checks for positive semi-definitness of a matrix $H$ via (notation adapted from the book):
$$aHa^*\geq 0.$$ I interpret the latter as $$\langle H^Ta, a\rangle \geq 0$$ which is equivalent to:
$$\langle a, \overline{(\left((H^T)^T\right)}a\rangle = \langle a,\overline{H}a \rangle \geq 0$$
However this is testing if the conjugate of $H$ is positive semidefinite.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: It think that should be $a^*Ha$? Unless $a$ is meant to be a row-vector or something? Anyway, your mistake seems to be in $\langle H^Ta, a\rangle$, which should be $\langle H^* a, a\rangle$.

Comment: Note also that $\langle x, Ay\rangle = \langle Ax, y\rangle$ when $A$ is self-adjoint.

Comment: sorry - I didn't mention it: a is stated to be a row-vector

Comment: In any case, $H$ is positive semidefinite if and only if $\overline{H}$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: Can you indicate a short proof of: $H$ is self-adjoint iff $\overline{H}$ is?

Comment: @P.Jo Let $y=\overline x$. Then 
$x^*\overline H x = \overline{y^*Hy} = y^*Hy \ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the confusion is that $\langle x, Ax\rangle$ assumes column vectors whereas $aHa^*$ assumes row vectors, so even $H^Ta$ is nonsensical (unless we define $H^T(a)$ to be the matrix product $aH^T$...? it gets messy quickly). But the main problem is that your $H^T$ should have been $H^*$.

Let me first assume that everything is column vectors to make it algebraically simpler. Then it would say $a^*Ha$. This is equal to $\langle Ha, a\rangle$ by definition, which is also equal to $\langle a, H^* a\rangle$ and $\langle a,Ha\rangle$ (the last one is only true because $H=H^*$). Nowhere will $H^T$ this appear, which was your mistake.

With row vectors we should probably write either $aHa^* = \langle a, aH\rangle$ or $aHa^* = \langle aH, a\rangle$, but I don't know if either convention is generally accepted. In any case, they are equivalent in this case because $\langle aH, a\rangle = \langle a, aH\rangle$ since $H$ is self-adjoint.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out - I need a moment to digest this. It gets quite messy with the notation